# if-then in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a command in SQL Server that should basically say

```
If table1.columnx = 1
then update table2 set comumnx = 1
```

It should be very simple but I cannot  come up with a solution.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, and what version?

Answer (score 11):

```
update t2
set columnx = 1
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.columnx = 1
```